# PowerShell 5.0 Get-Help -ShowWindow doesn't display detailed parameters description

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell 3.0 and 4.0 when running:

```
Get-Help Get-Service -ShowWindow
```

it displays new window with full description of GetService command (with detailed parameters description). When running the same command in PowerShell 5.0 it displays new window but only with simple description (without detailed parameters description). Is this a bug or future :) ?

Comment: Does it show the detailed parameter description without the `-ShowWindow`? Maybe an `Update-Help` helps?

Comment: `Update-Help` didn't help. Without `-ShowWindow` it displays detailed parameter description but you have to use `-Full` parameter which isn't available with `-ShowWindow` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that has been reported to Microsoft through Microsoft Connect for PowerShell:

[(PowerShell 5.0) -ShowWindow is not showing Description and Parameters - by Rupskin](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback/Details/1747915)